# Why Sonarqube stops before running completely?

Tags: java, sonarqube, java-11, devsecops

I am installing Sonarqube (community version) (v8). I know I need JDK 11, so I have installed it using Windows Installer. Whatsmore, I hace changed `wrapper.java.command` to `wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16\bin\java.exe` (I have tried `wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16\bin\java` too, without the `.exe`). It is not working, if I look into localhost:9000 the screen shows "loading" and in the prompt the process ends after one second o two. This is the output:

(I haved tried deleting temp folder's content and killing java task in task administrator too)

```java
StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2022.09.07 10:39:27 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.9.9.56886\temp
jvm 1    | 2022.09.07 10:39:27 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:50285]
jvm 1    | 2022.09.07 10:39:27 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.9.9.56886\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16\bin\java -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.9.9.56886\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.9.9.56886\temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.9.9.56886\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.9.9.56886\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
jvm 1    | 2022.09.07 10:39:27 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | 2022.09.07 10:39:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
jvm 1    | 2022.09.07 10:39:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [C:\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.9.9.56886]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.9.9.56886\temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/sonar-application-8.9.9.56886.jar;C:\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.9.9.56886\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.4.199.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\sonarqube\sonarqube-8.9.9.56886\temp\sq-process16684317784465325676properties
jvm 1    | 2022.09.07 10:40:03 WARN  app[][startup] ####################################################################################################################
jvm 1    | 2022.09.07 10:40:03 WARN  app[][startup] Default Administrator credentials are still being used. Make sure to change the password or deactivate the account.
jvm 1    | 2022.09.07 10:40:03 WARN  app[][startup] ####################################################################################################################
jvm 1    | 2022.09.07 10:40:18 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2022.09.07 10:40:18 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2022.09.07 10:40:18 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Can you extend this log with more info, because it is nearly impossible to get an idea of what is happening from this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its all I received in the console